# Retrieving Smart Card ID

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader

I have smart card's ATR and I  want to get its ID.  What APDU commands should i use?

If there isn't a command, how can this be achieved?

I'm completely new to smart cards and google doesn't help much. Thank you!

Comment: What specific ID are you looking for? What standards does the card comply to?

Comment: PS modded you down because of the missing information, may change to upvote if the information is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which card you were using either SCOSTA or any SLE cards?
I f you were using the SCOSTA contact cards the command to get the chip serial number is 
00 CA 02 46 
the response will be 61 XX
XX represents number of bytes
in the next command send 00 CA 02 46 XX this. You will get the chip serial number.
If you were using the Contact less SCOSTA cards the Get UID depends on the reader.